# Обработка данных на сервере и отправка данных на страницу

Tags: python, html, django

Всем привет.
Я не особо знаток разработки сайтов, так что мне нужна помощь
Допустим у человека открыт сайт test.com написанный на django.
Надо сделать обработку данных на сервере и отправку данных на страницу, без подзагрузок и прочего.
Например сделать отображение таймера, отсчитывающего время. Важно, что это должно работать не на js, тогда в таком случае таймер можно легко обмануть через консоль разработчика.

Comment: Сделайте таймер на JS, который будет синхронизироваться с сервера

Comment: А вообще вопрос в другом - кому нужно ставить свой таймер? Какую пользу это принесет злоумышленнику?

Comment: @ZaArs 
Пример с таймером был абстрактным, чтобы можно было понять, что я хочу от кода

Comment: Делать динамические страницы "без подгрузок", но не на JS звучит как форменный изврат, но если вам нужен таймер именно с сайта, можете попробовать сделать так: выводить на страницу iframe с таймером, и его уже обновлять кажые n секунд для синхронизации с сервером

Comment: Все равно нет смысла подменять данные которые приходят от сервера. Другое дело - подмена данных для отправки, но это возможно только если у вас в JS внедрен вредоносный код, который не вводил сам клиент

Comment: проверяйте ваш "абстрактный таймер" на сервере и не мучайтесь

Answer (score 0):

> Я не особо знаток разработки сайтов

Есть 2 варианта:

- Сокеты
- http API

Ни один из вариантов не будет работать без JS.
Сокет позволяет организовать чтение данных клиентом с сервера, тоесть сервер пишет в поток, клиент читает.
API - клиент дергает ручку на бэкенде и бэкэнд отдает данные. В этом случае бэкенд пассивно ждет и не имеет возможности пушить данные на клиент.

Если вы думате сделать SPA(SinglePageApplication-приложение которое работает без перезагрузки страницы) то на чистой джанге без JS это невозможно.